# Run grammar checker without spell checker in Word 2000

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to run Word 2000's grammar checker without also running the spelling checker?

I write a lot of technical documentation in French, and the grammar is more important than the spelling, but the spell checker slows me down because so many of the words are in English.

Comment: You should be able to add a custom dictionary, so you can add in an English dictionary so it won't catch any of those as spelling mistakes (At least you can do this in Word 2003... I assume you can in Word 2000 as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. I believe this is because the grammar checker relies on correct (or ignored) spelling to do it's work.

You can mark words that are in English as English and use both English and French dictionaries at the same time. That sounds like a royal pain if the English is mixed in a word at a time in the French text. There is a trick that can make it faster.

- Create a macro that sets the language to English
- Assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+1 for example)
- Save the macro and shortcut in the normal.dot template so it's available for all documents

To use the macro

- Select the English text
- Press the keyboard shortcut

Combine this with both English and French dictionaries and you should be able to do a full spelling and grammar check on the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Tools > Spelling and Grammar...
Options...
Untick all the Spelling options
Ok
```

This should work though, as `Wayne Johnston` points out, Grammar checking may require spelling to be correct to work properly.